# Intel Widi and Microsoft wireless Adapter

Tags: windows-7, windows

Can Intel Widi be installed on older Windows 7 Laptops ? I have windows 7 profesional , service pack 1 
H Elite book  8460p
4 gb ram 
64 bit op
core 15 proc

I'm trying to install drivers to allow this laptop to usse the microsoft wireless adapter . Any suggestions .

Comment: The driver would need to specifically indicate it supports Windows 7.  If it does not then the likelihood of it working is very slim.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use Intel's Widi on your laptop.  Widi requires compatible hardware (it's not just drivers).  Reading the PC review for your laptop (Elitebook 8460p), it specifically states "No Widi" in the cons section:

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2404181,00.asp

Since your hardware doesn't support it, you won't be able to use Intel's Widi.  You can check your laptop's compatibility with Widi using Intel's tool at:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/emerging-technologies/000014931.html